# Yootheme joomla template 2.5 remove content block in front page

Tags: joomla, frontpage

I'm manage to remove content part in front page (inner page still remain) in yootheme joomla 2.5, after go through several post and tutorial, I added following into a code:

```
<?php
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if($menu->getActive() !== $menu->getDefault()) : 
?>

<jdoc:include type="component" />

<?php endif;  ?>
```

after the hacked of the code, the content block was successfully removed the frontpage  article, but the block is still appear as blank box, however I've try System Output setting selected to NO in backend, but the content block was unable to display from front and inner page, how can I totally kick the frontpage blank box away?

Please advise & thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off blocks in this theme using the modules section of the joomla console, if you want to remove the default front page logo with the text bubbles, this is also in modules, but can be turned off in the yootheme template config, also accessible from your joomla console.

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
<?php
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if($menu->getActive() !== $menu->getDefault()) :
?>
                                    <?php if ($this['config']->get('system_output')) : ?>

                                            <section id="content" class="grid-block">

                                            <?php if ($this['modules']->count('breadcrumbs')) : ?>
                                            <?php echo $this['modules']->render('breadcrumbs'); ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php echo $this['template'] >render('content'); ?>

                                            </section>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
```